# Rails scope: Find records using class method rather than db column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

In my rails 4 app I have a model called `Property` that has the following class method:

```
def under_contract?
    self.contracts.last && self.contracts.last.accepted? ? true : false
end
```

What this does is it checks if the property has a contract associated with it and then whether that contract has been accepted.

I want to create a scope for properties that are rented (if you use the class method under_contract? on them it will return true). Here's what I tried doing to accomplish that:

```
scope :rented, -> {where(under_contract?: true)}
```

The problem is that under_contract is not a column in the db, it's just a class method, so I get an error saying "No Such Column".

Am I approaching this completely wrong or am i just missing something small?

Answer (score 1):

> class method

It is an [*instance* method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) - if it were class it would be `def self.under_contract?`

--

> Am I approaching this completely wrong

Yes.

---

## Context

Firstly, a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) is the same as a class method; it initializes a new instance of the class to return your data. Instance methods perform actions on already-invoked classes:

```
#app/models/property.rb
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
   def under_contract? #-> instance method
      ...
   end

   def self.under_contract #-> class method
      where under_contract: true 
   end
end
```

The above can be used as follows:

```
@property = Property.find x
@property.under_contract? #-> instance method

@properties = Property.under_contract #-> class method
@properties.each do |property|
    property.under_contract?
end
```

The difference is subtle but important. It lies at the root of your issues.

-

Secondly, you cannot mix class and instance methods. They have totally different scopes; you cannot call an instance method on a class method.

You cannot use a `scope` with an already invoked object. You have to either invoke the object & use an instance method, or use a scope to invoke the required objects initially.

---

## Fix

Do this:

```
#app/models/property.rb
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :contracts
   scope :rented, -> { joins(:contracts).where(accepted: true) }

   def under_contract?
      self.contracts.any? && self.contracts.exists(accepted: true)  #-> returns true / false
   end
end
```

This gives you a *scope* for pulling the `rented` properties from the db:

```
@properties = Property.rented
```

... as well as an instance method to determine if a specific property has been rented:

```
@property = Property.find x
@property.under_contract?
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. I solved my specific problem with the code below.

```
def under_contract
  self.contracts.any? && self.contracts.last.accepted?
end

scope :rented, -> {select { |p| p.under_contract == true}}
```

Comment: Watch out - this loads the entire table and then filters it down - will get very slow if your table gets large.

Comment: I was able to speed it up by first loading only properties that belonged to the current user, than selecting from those the ones that are rented. Here's what my modified code looks like `scope :rented, -> (user) {
  where("landlord_id = ?", user.id).select { |p| p.under_contract == true }
 }` and then in my controller `@rented = @properties.rented(current_user)` Thanks for the heads up, it was starting to get really slow as I added more properties.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're **accepted?** method on contracts looks like but assuming you have a **accepted:boolean** column in contracts then you can build your scope using **includes** like this ...

```
scope :rented, -> { includes(:contracts).where.not(contracts: { property_id: nil }).where(contracts: {accepted: true}) }
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to take in account that in order for a property to be accepted, the newest contract has to accepted.

Comment: I disagree. If you look at the **under_contract?** method (which is what the scope is attempting to do, you will see that it is simply checking that is 1.) has an associated contract and 2.) that contract is accepted? Which is what my solution is attempted to do